# VB.net swapping bits to send 32-bit signed integer to 32-bit MODBUS register

Tags: vb.net, modbus

I want to do a sequential write to multiple 32-bit modbus registers. By definition a holding register is 16-bits I need to have the bits swapped correctly when writing.

In the example below I want to send the value of "RSnumber" to 6 signed 32-bit MDOBUS registers. I use a "SwapBits" to convert to the 32-bit value. For example RSnumber = 125.

I understand I will need to swap the bits so the 23-bit value gets sent like:

0, 125

Unfortunately my swapbits function is not working properly.

My code looks like this:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (Not IsNumeric(MODBUStestValueTextBox.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(MODBUStestRegisterTextBox.Text)) Then
            MsgBox("At least one of the values given is not numeric; please perform a read or change the value before setting")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Setup MODBUS properties
        Dim modbusClientWriteTest As New ModbusClient("172.30.72.4", 502)
        modbusClientWriteTest.UnitIdentifier = 3
        modbusClientWriteTest.ConnectionTimeout = 1250

         Try
            modbusClientWriteTest.Connect()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        If modbusClientWriteTest.Connected Then
            Try
                Dim startaddress As Integer = CDbl(MODBUStestRegisterTextBox.Text)

                Dim RSnumber As Integer = CDbl(MODBUStestValueTextBox.Text)

                'Using Swap function
                Dim registerValues() As Integer = {SwapBits(RSnumber), SwapBits(RSnumber), SwapBits(RSnumber), SwapBits(RSnumber), SwapBits(RSnumber), SwapBits(RSnumber)}

                modbusClientWriteTest.WriteMultipleRegisters(startaddress, registerValues)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        modbusClientWriteTest.Disconnect()
    End Sub
```

This issue is occurring with the "SwapBits" function I made:

```
    Function SwapBits(originalValue16Bit As Integer) As Integer
        Dim SwappedValue() As Integer = {(originalValue16Bit >> 16), originalValue16Bit And &HFFFF}
        Return SwappedValue(0) Or SwappedValue(1)
    End Function
```

The values I'm sending are:

RSnumber = 125

I want 125 to be sent to the 32-bit MODBUS register but instead I am getting: 8192125.

I am getting the correct format from the SwapBits function: {0, 125}. The issues seems to how the values are sent from the SwapBits function back to the MODBUS write function. If I console.writeline the registerValues() I see the values being sent are {125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125) instead of {0, 125, ...}

If anyone has advice it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which Modbus library are you using? I'm guessing [EasyModbusTCP](https://github.com/rossmann-engineering/EasyModbusTCP.NET) in which case you can use [`ConvertIntToRegisters`](https://github.com/rossmann-engineering/EasyModbusTCP.NET/blob/master/EasyModbus/ModbusClient.cs#L442C29-L442C50). See [this](https://onecompiler.com/vb/3zyfn7bqj) ref your SwapBits implementation (but not really sure if thats what you need).